# How to delete root node in BST when it has only one child?

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, data-structures, binary-search-tree

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class BST {
  int data;
  BST *left, *right;
  public: 
    BST();
    BST(int);
    BST* Insert(BST*, int);
    void Delete(BST*, BST*, int);
    void Inorder(BST*);
};

BST::BST():data(0), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}

BST::BST(int value):BST() {
  data = value; 
}

BST* BST::Insert(BST *root, int value) {
  if(!root) {
    return new BST(value);
  }
  if(value > root->data) {
    root->right = Insert(root->right, value);
  } else {
    root->left = Insert(root->left, value);
  }
  return root;
}

void BST::Delete(BST *parent, BST *root, int value) {
  if(!root) {
    return;
  }
  if(root->data == value) {
    if(!root->left && !root->right) {
      if(parent) {
        if (parent->left == root) {
          parent->left = NULL;
        }
        else {
          parent->right = NULL;
        }
      }
      free(root);
      return;
    }
    if(!root->left || !root->right) {
      BST *child = root->left ? root->left : root->right;
      if(parent) {
        if (root == parent->left) {
          parent->left = child;
        }
        else {
          parent->right = child;
        }
        free(root);
      } else {
        // what do i have to do here ?
      }
      return;
    }
    BST *inorderSuccessor = root->right;
    parent = root;
    while (inorderSuccessor->left) {
      parent = inorderSuccessor;
      inorderSuccessor = inorderSuccessor->left;
    }
    root->data = inorderSuccessor->data;
    Delete(parent, inorderSuccessor, inorderSuccessor->data);
  }
  if(value > root->data) {
    Delete(root, root->right, value);
  } else {
    Delete(root, root->left, value);
  }
}

void BST::Inorder(BST *root) {
  if(!root) {
    return;
  }
  Inorder(root->left);
  cout << root->data << " ";
  Inorder(root->right);
}

int main() {
  BST bst, *root = NULL;
  root = bst.Insert(root, 4);
  bst.Insert(root, 2);
  // bst.Insert(root, 5);
  bst.Insert(root, 1);
  bst.Insert(root, 3);
  bst.Delete(NULL, root, 4);
  bst.Inorder(root);
  return 0;
}
```

When i do free(root) whole of tree gets deleted.
I have done almost everything I know but it just doesn't run correctly.
I am keeping track of parent node in the function itself.
I am using recursion to do that. I can tell a node is root of tree if parent is null.
Everything else is working fine. I have checked all the other cases.

Comment: There's no way you can implement a `Delete` function with this signature and be able to end up with the empty tree after the delete. Do yourself a favor and create 2 seperate types: `BST` containing the functions that should be available to the user and another object type (I'll call it `Node` for convenience) for storing `data`, and pointers `left` and `right` to `Node`s. Preferably make this an private inner type of `BST`. This would allow you to represent the empty tree as an object simply containing  a pointer a `Node` with value `nullptr`.

Comment: Also even though you're not required to add parameter names to function declarations I'd still recommend doing it, since this is the part that usually goes into headers so someone using your class may see nothing but that info in which case they have no information about the purpose of those parameters. (In addition to that I'd recommend adding a comment documenting the functionality provided by the function, the purpose of the parameters and the return value, but a parameter name is the bare minimum to make that class usable without access to the implementation.)

Comment: Btw: If you don't want to change too much of your code you could change the signature of your `Delete` function to `BST* BST::Delete(BST* node, int value)` and return the value to replace the old node with.